# Let $v_1 = (1, 0); v_2 = (1,-1) \space\text{and} \space v_3 = (0, 1).$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck on the following problem :

> Let $v_1 = (1, 0); v_2 = (1,-1) \space\text{and} \space v_3 = (0, 1).$ How many linear transformations
>   $T \colon \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ are there such that $Tv_1 = v_2; Tv_2 = v_3$ and $Tv_3 = v_1?$ The options are as follows:
>
> (A) $3!$
>   (B) $3$
>   (C) $1$
>   (D) $0$

What I observed that $v_2=v_1-v_3$ and so $T(v_2)=T(v_1)-T(v_3) \implies v_3=v_2-v_1$.
But I do not know how to progress from here. Any idea?

Comment: I think you should have $v_1=v_2+v_3$.  Then by linearity of $T$, we should have $v_2=T(v_1)=T(v_2+v_3)=T(v_2)+T(v_3)=v_3+v_1,$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a straight forward solution. Every linear transformation $T\colon \mathbb R^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb R^2$ can be represented as a $2\times 2$ matrix, so you want to find $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ and $a_4$ such that

\[\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & a_2 \\ a_3 & a_4\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix} \: \Leftrightarrow \: \begin{pmatrix}a_1 \\ a_3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}\]
and
\[\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & a_2 \\ a_3 & a_4\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \: \Leftrightarrow \: \begin{pmatrix}a_1-a_2 \\ a_3-a_4\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\]
and
\[\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & a_2 \\ a_3 & a_4\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \: \Leftrightarrow \: \begin{pmatrix}a_2 \\ a_4\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\]

Now it's obvious that there are no such matrix, and so the answer is (d), 0.

*Actually you've the answer in front of you too. Assume that there is some such $T$. Since $v_2 = v_1+v_3$ we can use the linearity of the transformation to get $v_3 = v_2+v_1$. Combine these two equations to get $v_1 = 0$, which is a contradiction, and again the answer is (d), 0.*